# How to handle when request payload is empty in jersey REST?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

**Request: (POST)**

When I am sending with empty object like {}. I was able to handled this request. But, When I am sending without mention any its giving below.

I have a RESTful web service, written using Jersey, that looks like this:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response myAction(RequestObject requestObject) {
    // do some action
}
```

**Exception**

```
**java.io.EOFException**: No content to map to Object due to end of input
            at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2433)
            at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2366)
            at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1162)
            at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:410)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:474)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:123)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:46)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:183)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
            at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
            at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1136)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2555)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2544)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What is the point of sending POST request without any data?

Comment: Use try catch block

Comment: By mistake, User will send empty request from API sometimes. In this case we should prompt him as not a valid request.

Comment: @SumeshTG I have directly getting exception. Anyway I have tested with try catch also.

Comment: Then you should handle this issue from rest call itself not in recieving end.

Comment: @SumeshTG I should handle at my side only.

Comment: Use filters or interceptor inorder to bypass this issue . You cannot do anything inside of your handle method.

Comment: Catch it with an [ExceptionMapper](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/representations.html#d0e6352) and send back 400 Bad Request to the client.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I got it. Thank you.